# Spectrum of an $\ell^2$ operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I have trouble finding the spectra of the following operator $T$:

$T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$, $x = (\xi_i)_i \in \ell^2$:
\begin{equation}
Tx = (0,\frac{\xi_1}{1}, \frac{\xi_2}{2}, \ldots)
\end{equation}

Crearly it isn't invertible, so $0 \in \sigma(T)$. Also, i have proved that $\sigma_p(T)= \emptyset$. 
Why $\{0\} = \sigma(T) = \sigma_r(T)$?

Comment: What does your index range over? Is the lowest index 0 or 1? Is $x= \{ \xi_j \}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ or $\{\xi_j \}_{j=1}^{\infty}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it is easy to see that
$$T^nx = \left(\underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_n, \frac{\xi_1}{n!}, \frac{\xi_2}{(n+1)!}, \ldots, \frac{\xi_k}{(n+k-1)!}, \ldots\right)$$

This implies
$$\|T^nx\|_2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{\xi_k}{(n+k-1)!}\right|^2 \le \frac1{n!^2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\xi_k|^2 =\frac1{n!^2} \|x\|_2^2 $$
so $\|T^n\| \le \frac1{n!}$. Hence the spectral radius is
$$r(T) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \|T^n\|^{\frac1n} \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac1{n!}\right)^{\frac1n} = 0$$

so $\sigma(T) \subseteq \{0\}$. Since $0 \in \sigma(T)$ it follows $\sigma(T) = \{0\}$.

$T$ is injective so $0 \notin \sigma_p(T)$. Also, $\operatorname{Im} T \subseteq \{x = (\xi_i)_i \in \ell^2 : \xi_1 = 0\}$, which is not dense in $\ell^2$ so $0 \notin \sigma_c(T)$. Hence $0 \in \sigma_r(T)$.

Therefore $\sigma(T) = \sigma_r(T) = \{0\}$ and $\sigma_p(T) = \sigma_c(T) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question, the contiuous spectrum is $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ that $\overline{Im (T- \lambda I)} = \ell^2$. This is equivalent to $Im T$ being dense in $\ell^2$?

Comment: @BarryAllen $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(T-\lambda I)} = \ell^2$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Im}(T-\lambda I)$ being dense in $\ell^2$. In our case we have $\lambda = 0$ so we consider $\operatorname{Im} T$.